# Libgdx псевдо 3d дорога

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx, 3d, 2d

Создаю дорогу по примеру http://www.extentofthejam.com/pseudo.

Но есть проблема в производительности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая разделительная полоса, граница дороги... каждая линия является отдельным элементом. Рисую все в `SpriteBatch`.
При рендере скачет фпс (все зависит от дороги, если поднимаемся вверх то фпс поднимается до 60, т.к. нужно меньше отрисовывать... запускал на Redmi Note 3 pro).

Вызвал `renderCalls` и увидел что игра отсылает очень много текстур на отрисовку, вплоть до 800+.

**Посоветуйте каким образом можно оптимизировать или сделать дорогу?**

Конечно можно уменьшить дистанцию горизонта, убрать разделительные полосы и края, да и уменьшить количество спрайтов окружения (деревья, дома..). Что существенно уменьшит количество текстур и повысит производительность, но будет выглядеть скудно...

Answer (score 0):

> Вызвал renderCalls и увидел что игра отсылает очень много текстур на отрисовку, вплоть до 800+.

Не делайте так. 800+ renderCalls на картинку в вопросе - ОЧЕНЬ много. У вас же там максимум 20 * 6 = 120 элементов. Плюс, в вашем примере, текстуры вообще не обязательны (если речь только про дорогу).